# inject $q into mockService before other services use mockService

Tags: javascript, angularjs, karma-runner, angularjs-service

I have a UserService which has myService as a dependency. The trouble is, within UserService, myService.getAll is called. However in my karma jasmine tests it complains that myService.getAll is undefined. This is because I haven't added the getAll method to mockMyService before UserService is created by $provide. I would have created the getAll method earlier but getAll has $q as a dependency and I can't get hold of $q in time. I can't use the injector until after i've used $provide. how can I attached the getAll method to mockMyService with $q before UserService calls mockMyService.getAll?

```
beforeEach(function() {
  mockMyService = {};

  module('plunker');

  module(function ($provide) {
    $provide.value('myService', mockMyService);
  });
  /* at this point - getAll is called */

  inject(function ($rootScope, _$q_) {
    rootScope = $rootScope
    q = _$q_;
  });

  mockMyService.getAll = function () {
    var deferred = q.defer();
    deferred.resolve([
      { itemText: "Foo" },
      { itemText: "Bar" }
    ]);
    return deferred.promise;
  };
}
```

Comment: Where is the UserService part ?

Comment: UserService is a provider with a this.$get which has a myService as a dependency. Inside the $get, myService.getAll is called before $get returns the UserService.

Comment: Can you include the `UserService` part that uses `myService.getAll`? Thanks.